# In Google App Engine, how do I create a model with a specific ID?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have backed up all of the entities for a model in a CSV file. I am recovering the entities to my local dev_server and would like to recreate the entities with an ID in the csv file (similar to how bulkloader does). How do I pass in the desired ID for my new entity in my create statement?

```
playerID = 1234
player = Player(created = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 25, 9, 20, 5, 757227), 
                nickname = u'chris', 
                email = u'chris@home.com')
player.put()
```

What do I add to Player() to create the player with player.key().id()==1234 when I call put()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to allocate the id range using [allocate_id_range](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html), to make sure to reserve the ids for those entities.

And then just build the key manually, and pass it to `Player` constructor:

```
k = Key.from_path('Player', playerID)
player = Player(key = k, ...)
player.put()
```